# Display Image Uploaded Area in Dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

[image]

Hello!
I am implementing Dropzone.js for making gallary.
I am facing a little problem. By deafult, Dropzone shows blank container area with clickable effect to upload one or more photos. But i want to override this effect and wants to show image upload options like in image given above .

So far,i tried to override this by overriding css but the result was like this.

[image]

What css code  should i target to achieve the desired effect ?

dropzone.css

```
.dropzone, .dropzone * {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.dropzone {
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 2px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 20px; }
  .dropzone.dz-clickable {
    cursor: pointer; }
    .dropzone.dz-clickable  {
      cursor: default; }
    .dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message, .dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message * {
      cursor: pointer; 
      border: 2px dotted black;
    }
  .dropzone.dz-started .dz-message {
    display: none; }
  .dropzone.dz-drag-hover {
    border-style: solid; }
    .dropzone.dz-drag-hover .dz-message {
      opacity: 0.5; }
  .dropzone .dz-message {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0; }
  .dropzone .dz-preview {
      //border: 2px dotted grey;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 16px;
    min-height: 100px; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:hover {
      z-index: 1000; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-details {
        opacity: 1; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image {
      border-radius: 20px;
      background: #999;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, #ddd); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-details {
      opacity: 1;

    }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview {
     // background: yellow; 
    background: white;}
      .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview .dz-details {
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        transition: opacity 0.2s linear; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-remove {
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-remove:hover {
        text-decoration: underline; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-details {
      opacity: 1; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details {
      z-index: 20;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
      min-width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: 2em 1em;
      text-align: center;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      line-height: 150%; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        font-size: 16px; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename {
        white-space: nowrap; }
        .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:hover span {
          border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
          background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
        .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:not(:hover) {
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis; }
          .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:not(:hover) span {
            border: 1px solid transparent; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename span, .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size span {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        padding: 0 0.4em;
        border-radius: 3px; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-image img {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -o-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
      filter: blur(8px); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image {
      //border: 1px double grey;
      border-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      z-index: 10; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image img {
        display: block; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark {
      -webkit-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -moz-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -ms-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -o-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-mark {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -moz-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -ms-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      -o-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1); }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark, .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 500;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -27px;
      margin-top: -27px; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark svg, .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark svg {
        display: block;
        width: 54px;
        height: 54px; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-processing .dz-progress {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
      transition: all 0.2s linear; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-complete .dz-progress {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview:not(.dz-processing) .dz-progress {
      -webkit-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      -moz-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      -ms-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      -o-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
      animation: pulse 6s ease infinite; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 1000;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      height: 16px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -8px;
      width: 80px;
      margin-left: -40px;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      border-radius: 8px;
      overflow: hidden; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload {

        background: #333;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666, #444);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
        transition: width 300ms ease-in-out; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-message {
      display: block; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error:hover .dz-error-message {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto; }
    .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message {
      pointer-events: none;
      z-index: 1000;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-size: 13px;
      top: 130px;
      left: -10px;
      width: 140px;
      background: #be2626;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #be2626, #a92222);
      padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
      color: white; }
      .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -6px;
        left: 64px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #be2626; }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML just wrap the form element assigned to dropzone in a div like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <form action="/file-upload"
                 class="dropzone"
                 id="my-awesome-dropzone">
   </form>
</div>
```

and then assign an image to your wrapper div on your css:

```
  #wrapper{
    background-image: url(dropText.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15em;
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  #wrapper:hover{
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.4s  ease-in-out 1s;
    background-image: url(uploadPic.png);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

remember to change the form opacity too:

```
#my-awesome-dropzone{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Without previewing, Images are direct inserting into db

Comment: Could you explain me what you mean by that? the code I provided you is for replacing the blank container area with an image of your choice.

Comment: Simple.
I meant to say that by default, you just click anywhere in container and you are redirected to your pc location to upload file.
You select file and click ok. The file is previewed and inserted into db.
.......Now what i want, i want that in container  i could display some image like in my question, the user clicks on it and the rest will be the same

Comment: some image means one or more multiple boxes to select image from your pc to upload

Comment: you mean a thumbnail with the preview of the selected image?

Comment: Yes exactly!... That's i was trying to say but didn't remember the name...
Before selection there would be a some thumbnail with text or icon etc, which later changed with the uploaded image.

Comment: So as I stated already, the solution I provided gives you all you need to achieve that

Comment: i implemented your solution, that just direct insert the image into db without displaying the selected image in thumbnail before and after uploading

Comment: because that wasn't the question. You must ask a new question if you want a solution for that.

Comment: I think that was obvious and not needed to explicitly mention.
Who wants to direct insert the image in db without previewing that whether it is an image or not.
It's the part of this system.
Anyways, if you have some idea then do tell me, i will up-vote for you here.